# Tables are not lining up horizontally

Tags: html, css, spring

I'm making  task manager application on Spring and faced problem - I need to make a number of tables (they will be columns for tasks), but I need them to be placed side by side, not one under another.

My code does not create each table individually, I take all the data from the database and creating each tables with help of only ONE table code (see below part of code):

```
<div th:switch="${col}"  > // table in database
    <div th:case="*"  >

        <table style="background-color: forestgreen; width:20%; float:left"  >

            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="col : ${col}">
                <td th:text="${col.name}"></td>

                <td style="width: auto"><a th:href="@{col_update/{id}(id=${col.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
                <td style="width: auto"><a th:href="@{col_delete/{id}(id=${col.id})}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>

            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><a href="/col_create" class="btn btn-primary">Create new column</a></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have tried using right align, inline-block and some other solutions, but it didn't help. How can I make them be placed side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the tables appear under each other is because each table is inside a `div` element which is 100% width by default. So even though your table width is 20%, each table has its own full-width parent which are being placed under each other.

Instead of adding the width & layout CSS to the table, you can add it to the outermost div of each table so the divs line up beside each other, e.g.:

```
<div style="width:20%; float:left" th:switch="${col}"  > // table in database
    <div th:case="*"  >
        <table style="background-color: forestgreen;" >

            TABLE CONTENT HERE

        </table>
        <p><a href="/col_create" class="btn btn-primary">Create new column</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that you might want to consider using CSS `grid` or `flexbox` instead of `float` or `inline-block` though, as they both can have issues.

**To use [CSS grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout):**

You just need to add an outer wrapper to contain all the divs with tables, and apply the grid CSS to it - you don't need to set the width, float, display etc on any of the children.

For example, to make each of the columns for the tables be 20% wide - or 1/5th of the space - you can use the `style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);"`, e.g.

```
<!-- Add outer wrapper with grid CSS - this is where we add all the CSS for layout -->

<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);"> 

    <!-- All of your divs with tables go inside this wrapper. 
         We don't need to give them width, display, float etc. - the grid css does it all -->

    <div th:switch="${col}"  > // table in database
        <div th:case="*"  >
            <table style="background-color: forestgreen;"  >
                TABLE CONTENTS HERE
            </table>
            <p><a href="/col_create" class="btn btn-primary">Create new column</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:switch="${col}"  > // table in database
        <div th:case="*"  >
            <table style="background-color: forestgreen;"  >
                TABLE CONTENTS HERE
            </table>
            <p><a href="/col_create" class="btn btn-primary">Create new column</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    MORE TABLES....

</div> <!-- Close the outer grid wrapper -->
```

Comment: thank you so much=) your answer didnt help me directly, but it made me rethink what i need and i added display:table cell to my tr block:   <tr style="display: table-cell"th:each="col : ${col}">

Comment: @Daeris Glad I could help! Its difficult when trying to work with the code rather than the HTML that is generated because we have to guess at the output, but glad this helped in some way :)